# Coding Temperature Program With Sub Variables

Tags: vb.net

i'm currenly trying out this program that i made, it involves changing the entered number(temperature) to either Celsius or Fahrenheit. It uses 2 radio buttons(radCelsius, radFahrenheit), a convert button(btnConvert)an Exit button(btnExit) an Input button(txtTemp), and the "result"(lblResult) The problem that i'm having is that it's not giving me any numbers when i click the convert button. here's the code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
Private Sub CalcTemp(ByVal dblCel As Double,
                     ByVal dblFah As Double,
                      ByVal dblTemp As Double)
    'calculates Temperature

    If radCelsius.Checked Then

        dblCel = (dblTemp * 9 / 5 + 32)
    Else
        dblFah = (dblTemp - 32 * 5 / 9)
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub ClearLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs
                       ) Handles txtTemp.TextChanged, radCelsius.Click, radFahrenheit.Click
    lblResult.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtTemp_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtTemp.Enter
    txtTemp.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim dblCelsius As Double
    Dim dblFahrenheit As Double
    Dim dblTemp As Double

    Double.TryParse(radCelsius.Checked.ToString, dblCelsius)
    Double.TryParse(radFahrenheit.Checked.ToString, dblFahrenheit)
    dblTemp = Val(txtTemp.Text)
    Call CalcTemp(dblCelsius, dblFahrenheit, dblTemp)

    lblResult.Text = txtTemp.ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

I've tried converting the txtTemp to string(then adding CStr to txtTemp) but it's still not giving me any numbers when i hit the "Convert" button. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few comments here, the first thing that jumps out at me is that you are trying to convert a RadioButton Checked value to a Double i.e `Double.TryParse(radCelsius.Checked.ToString,dblCelsius)` those two lines are accomplishing nothing and can be gotten rid of. The second is that your `CalcTemp` Subroutine is working correctly but you are not using any of the values from it. I would make it a Function and return your calculated result to your calling function.

**Modified Code**

```
Private Function CalcTemp(ByVal dblTemp As Double)
    'calculates Temperature
    Dim result As Double
    If radCelsius.Checked Then

        result = (dblTemp * 9 / 5 + 32)
    Else
        result = ((dblTemp - 32) * 5 / 9) 'Note changed parenthesis for your math to be correct
    End If

    Return result

End Function

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim dblTemp As Double
    lblResult.Text = CalcTemp(dblTemp).ToString()
End Sub
```

---

Modified example using ByRef

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
    Dim dblTemp As Double
    dblTemp = Val(txtTemp.Text)
    CalcTemp(dblTemp)
    lblResult.Text = dblTemp.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub CalcTemp(ByRef dblTemp As Double)
    'calculates Temperature
    If radCelsius.Checked Then
        dblTemp = (dblTemp * 9 / 5 + 32)
    Else
        dblTemp = ((dblTemp - 32) * 5 / 9)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your reply. I'm just wondering if I could still run the program correctly just by using a Sub Procedure(what i'm aiming for) and  not by using the Function Procedure. I kind of want to use the sub procedure CalcTemp, and then call it at the click procedure, then again i'm not sure if that's even possible. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You will need to pass your value ByRef not ByVal like the other answer states, I will try to give you and example also.

Comment: An example would be fantastic, thanks!
Also, for clarification, i'm intending for the dblTemp to be the textbox(txtTemp) to where the user to enter a number that they want to convert to.

Comment: @CardisEtramaDiRaizel see if that is what you are wanting

Comment: The modified code that you presented gave me numbers. But when I enter 32 at the txtTemp(which is dblTemp at this case), and i click the Celsius Radio button, it gives me 32, but when i Click the Fahrenheit button, it gives me -17.777

Comment: As for my original code,( with the proper ByRef and with the fixed parenthesis) It gives me "System.Windows..." at the result bar(lblResult)

Comment: It gives me zero, double check your equation's parenthesis. as far as your original equation you are calling a ToString method on the textbox which is returning the string description of the object. You need to put a Boolean there to check for Celsius and use the corresponding value that was modified by your sub.

Comment: Alright, i'll try to implement what you said. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ByVal` to `ByRef` for the subroutine calculating the temperature, since it looks like that's what you're intending those arguments to be used as.

Try this:

```
Private Sub CalcTemp(ByRef dblCel As Double,
                     ByRef dblFah As Double,
                      ByVal dblTemp As Double)
    'calculates Temperature

    If radCelsius.Checked Then

        dblCel = (dblTemp * 9 / 5 + 32)
    Else
        dblFah = (dblTemp - 32 * 5 / 9)
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this, but it gave me "System.Windows..." For the result.